# Reactivate Dormant Processes in Windows7

Tags: windows-7, cpu, cygwin, priority

I have a very computationally intensive program (which I wrote in python) and starting two days ago I ran 6 copies of it in parallel (using 6 Cygwin terminals on a Mac Book Pro running Windows7 in bootcamp).  This was enough to max out my 4 core (8 logical cores from hyperthreading) machine at the time.  For some reason, after 2.5 days even though all 6 processes are still running, my CPUs are at less than half use.  When I use task manager I see 60% idle and 3 of the 6 python2.7 processes claim 13% and 3 of the python2.7 processes claim 0%.  I would like them to again max out my machine's capabilities.

For each of the processes I increased the priority to 'High' or realtime but this didn't seem to have any effect.  How can I make these programs become active again and use as much CPU as possible?  These processes have important state information which I would like to preserve -- is there anyway to force a program dump and then resume from that dump with the same state? Also any guesses as to why those programs would stop using full capacity after several days (my guess is some sort of overheating issue put them into a sleep state but I have no idea)?  Thanks.

Edit: Additional potentially relevant information includes, these processes can make internet requests and read/write files which I understand could lead to locking.  However, the file that they all write to has been successfully updated since they seemed to stop (by one of the 13% processes) and those active processes also successfully made web calls...

Comment: Do you know they are still running computations?

Comment: In three of them I can see updates being printed (albeit slower than normal) so I assume these are the ones getting 13% CPU, the others I see no change so they may not be running even though task manager shows them and they still have memory reserved.

Answer (score 0):

Mystery (unfortunately) solved: the scripts had somehow gotten hung when trying to make a web call (even though other copies continued to successfully do so). I had to hard kill the processes and lose some state that had generated but I restructured my program to always save before making the web call so I won't lose state if this happens in the future.  Sorry the solution wasn't more exciting - it doesn't seem that processes are able to be in a sleep state like I thought was happening.